# javascript popup number-picker to an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, input-field, numberpicker

I'm looking for a script that allows me to enter numbers with decimal values in field​​.

Something like http://keith-wood.name/calculator.html

But simply, only numbers and decimal point.

I have a form that I want fill it only with mouse (no keyboard)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it